# iPhone and iPad wordpress menu BAD behavior

Tags: iphone, css, wordpress, menu

On this site : [mecanomedic.com](http://mecanomedic.com/), the menu template work fine in "normal" desktop browser, but dont slide down on ipad-iphone device. What can be the problem ?

Some tell me it's a css problem, but HOW safari desktop work ?

Comment: This is a css question, so _off topic_. Also "broken" is not a very good description...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the menu expansion relies on the user hovering with a mouse. On touch devices like iPads & iPhones, the hovering gesture can't be replicated because there's only one input- touch. If I were you, I'd take a look at Twitter's Bootstrap menu setup and perhaps use media queries to serve up a different menu on smaller screen sizes.

[Here's an example of a Bootstrap navigation bar in action (you'll have to inspect the code to see how it works)](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/starter-template.html).

Answer (score 1):

Add a `href` to the top-level `<a>`'s so that they can be focusable:

```
<a href="#">Produits</a>
```

Elements that are focusable receive mouse events and hover styles when the user taps on them.

Answer (score 0):

As @Matt stated, the problem is that your menu relies on a hover event and unfortunately that event is unavailable on touch screen devices.

One way to fix this would be to:

1. Check if the current user's device is an iOS device
2. If the device is an iOS device, use javascript to trigger a menu item's "show event" when the menu button is CLICKED instead of ROLLED OVER / HOVERED.

This would result in the menu being shown when the user taps a menu button.